# How to pass result from Select-Object to a command as a parameter

Tags: powershell

So I have a HyperV machine, and I can get the IP address thus:

```
Get-VM -VMName localdev | Select -ExpandProperty Networkadapters | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddresses | Select-Object -First 1
```

What I can't figure is how to 'pipe' this to SSH to connect to the machine in a single line.

```
Get-VM ....... | Select-Object -First 1 | ssh
```

^^^ this doesn't work.

I can do this but it's lacking in elegance:

```
$localdevip = Get-VM -VMName localdev | Select -ExpandProperty Networkadapters | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddresses |Select-Object -First 1
ssh $localdevip
```

Although this works, I want to understand Powershell better. How can I funnel the result from the `Select-Object` call into the parameter for the command (in the example it's SSH but could be anything) without assigning a variable?

Comment: Is the IP Address just the output? You can use a *calculated property* to narrow it down to just one `Select-Object` including the `-Fist 1` parameter

Comment: Yes, it literally outputs only `1.2.3.4` yet if I add `| ssh` it behaves as though I've passed no parameters and shows the help text.

Comment: the posted answer is what i was going to suggest, with a few changes. SSH is not a powershell cmdlet, meaning it does not accept pipeline input.

Comment: Please, do post an answer if there's a better way that makes it more pure Powershell. I just couldn't figure out where the output vanished to, but I'm coming from a Bash/Linux background where things work differently.

Comment: I'd keep the two-liner, because it is easier to debug.

Comment: Easier to debug, true. But sometimes it's good for learning how to make that one-liner, sometimes because I like shell history and the up arrow, and sometimes because I want to be sure the IP address hasn't changed in the second between query and command (unlikely....).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ssh (Get-VM -VMName localdev | Select -ExpandProperty Networkadapters | Select -ExpandProperty IPAddresses |Select-Object -First 1)
```

Comment: Bingo. This does it exactly as needed, thank you.

Comment: Since OP mention "elegeance", this is a bit shorter and might be easer to read and type. `ssh (Get-VM -VMName localdev).Networkadapters.IPAddresses[0]`